# mongodb aggregation $group the $sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a star schema like this:

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema
  user:
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: "User"
  mod:
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: "Mod"
  time_bucket:
    raw: Date
    hour: String
    day: String
    week: String
    month: String
    quarter: String
    year: String   

Schema.virtual("date").get () ->
  return time_bucket[0].raw
.set (date) ->
  date = new Date date
  @time_bucket =
    raw:      date
    hour:     "#{date.getFullYear()}-#{date.getMonth()}-#{date.getDate()}-#{date.getHours()}"
    day:      "#{date.getFullYear()}-#{date.getMonth()}-#{date.getDate()}"
    week:     "#{date.getFullYear()}-#{date.getMonth()}-#{date.getWeek()}"
    month:    "#{date.getFullYear()}-#{date.getMonth()}"
    quarter:  "#{date.getFullYear()}-#{date.getQuarter()}"
    year:     "#{date.getFullYear()}"
```

The mod field corresponds to a mod, which can have many stars.

I am trying to get trending mods like this:

```
Star.aggregate [
    {
      $limit : 6
    }
    {
      $match:
        "time_bucket.month": "#{date.getFullYear()}-#{date.getMonth()}"
    }
    {
      $group:
        _id: "$mod"
        stars:
          "$sum": 1
    }
    {
      $sort : {
        "stars": -1
        }
    }

  ], (err, docs) ->
    Star.populate docs,
      path: "_id",
      model: "Mod",
      select: "slug name summary author created lastUpdated"
    , (err, docs) ->
      data.trendingMods = docs
```

But this doesn't work. I can get the number of stars in a week for 6 mods, but I can't sort them :(. **How to sort them in order to get the mods that has more stars than the others?**

Comment: Not sure what your problem is here. You have `$limit` at the start of the pipeline. If you want results over the whole month then that needs to be the "last" step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NeilLunn, the `$limit`was at the beginning whereas it should have been after `$group`:

```
  Star.aggregate [
    {
      $match:
        "time_bucket.month": "#{date.getFullYear()}-#{date.getMonth()}"
    }
    {
      $group:
        _id: "$mod"
        stars:
          "$sum": 1
    }
    {
      $limit : 6
    }
    {
      $sort : {
        "stars": -1
        }
    }

  ], (err, docs) ->
```

Thank you!